# how to reduce the time complexity from O(n) to O(1) for these custom object lists?

Tags: c++, list, time-complexity

```
#include <stdio.h>

Class XObject
{
    int id;
    char *type;
}
Class XSubObject : XObject
{
    int remark;
    char* place;
}
```

**Sorry for my bad example, but more or less data looks like this. 
std::vector objects;
data stored in objects are like this:
`#1=XObject(1001,"chair"), #2=XObject(1002,"spoon"), #3=XSubObject(1004,"table",2,"center"), #4=XSubObject(1005,"item",0,"left")` and so..on

we cna have different XObjects with same types.

```
Class XStructure
{
    XObject parent;
}

Class XStructureRow
{
    XObject child;
    XStructure parentStruct;
}
```

std::vector structures;
data stored in Structures are like this:
`#5=XStructure(NULL), #7=XStructure(#1),#8=XStructure(#2),#9=XStructure(#3),#10=XStructure(#4)` and so..on

std::vector structurerows;
data stored in Structures are like this:
`XStructureRow(#4,#5), XStructureRow(#2,#1),XStructureRow(#2,#7),XStructureRow(#3,#10),XStructureRow(#4,#8)` and so..on

How can i write a fast alogirthm that starts with XObject and finds it in which structurerow and fetching its structure and fetching its parent. For ex, I want to retrieve all the parents of Object with name "table"
and retrive its parents with name "chair".

My written algorithm is:

```
std::vector<XObject> getParents(XObject "chair")
{
    std::vector<XObject> objs;
    for (int i=0;i<structurerows.size() ;i++ )
    {
        XStructurerow sr=structurerows[i];
        XStructutre parent= sr.fetchParent();
        if(parent!=NULL)
        {
            if(parent.fetchName()=="chair")
                objs.push_back(parent);
        }
    }
    return objs;
}
```

if i have to fetch all the objects parents then it is taking too much time if i have huge data. I mean is there any solution that helps to find the parent objects at O(1) way instead iterating the complete loop? I want to fetch these parents with minimal iterations. Here the complexity is O(n) which i am no satisfied. I hope i made some valid points. Suggestions please..

Comment: can you please re-read your text, fix the typos and extend the example for clarity?

Comment: After reading throught you post it makes me want to say "switch to gentoo linux recompile your entire system with the proper flags and instruction set and you will gain a 6% performance" but however try some compiler flags they are nice

Comment: This can't really work anyway, the way you lay it out here: to store objects _derived_ from `XObject`, you need polymorphic pointers (`unique_ptr` would probably be the right kind here), it's not possible to simply store by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to "find" something with O(1) complexity is to use a hash-table.  The process of creating a hash-value from a key-value and then accessing the object indexed into the table by that hash-value will have O(1) complexity.  Otherwise any other search algorithm will at best be O(log n) for a sorted list or sorted tree-type structure.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions.

First, your getParents() function is making multiple copies of objects and arrays.  It constructs a new instance of vector called objs, fills it up with **copies** of items in the row.  Then returns a **copy** of the array (which creates a new copy of each object, which creates copies of its members).  That's likely the root cause of your performance problems.

Second your class hierarchy has classes with "child" and "parent" objects, but are storing **copies** of these XObject instances. So if you were to update one of these objects independently, all the parent and child objects you think are referring to them have a different copy.  (And hence, will create some strange bugs later especially since the base classes contain pointers).  Your object relationships in the class declarations should be via pointers, not instance copies.

Third, string comparisons during a lookup algorithm are also harsh on performance.  You should represent your objects unique key by integers if at all possible.

Not knowing anything else about your problem set, if you addressed those three things, you'd likely have better performance and wouldn't care about finding the O(1) solution.

Now to actually answer your question:

I would keep a map or (hash_map) table of arrays to track all the objects of a certain type.  That is:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<XObject*>> lookupmap;
```

Then as each object is created, you can look up it's type in "lookupmap" and add it:

```
void OnObjectCreated(XObject* pObj)
{
    std::string strType(pObj->type);

    lookupmap[strType].push_back(pObj);
}
```

I'll leave the part where you use std::map or std::hash_map as an exercise for you.

Comment: thanks...I hope this would work..let you know after i re-engineering the solution.